# Trying to remove last element in a list using a Node class and a Linked List class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, linked-list

For this code, I'm trying to remove the last add object of a list using a Node class and a LinkedList class. I have this code right here but it doesn't work for some reason. I think it's because the code doesn't work if the list is empty but I'm not sure how to solve that.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, init_data):
        self.data = init_data
        self.next = None

    def get_data(self):
        return self.data

    def get_next(self):
        return self.next

    def set_data(self, new_data):
        self.data = new_data

    def set_next(self, new_next):
        self.next = new_next

class LinkedList:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def print_all(self):
        current = self.head
        while current != None:
            print(current.get_data())
            current = current.get_next()

    def add(self, item):
        new_node = Node(item)
        new_node.set_next(self.head)
        self.head = new_node

    def remove_from_tail(self):
        current = self.head
        previous = current
        while current.get_next() != None:
            previous = current
            current = current.get_next()
        previous.set_next(None)
        return current.get_data()
```

when trying to run the following lines with the code above,

```
my_list = LinkedList()

my_list.add('dog')
my_list.add('cat')
my_list.add('bit')
my_list.add('ask')

print(my_list.remove_from_tail())
print(my_list.remove_from_tail())

my_list.print_all()
```

I'm getting the following output:

```
<__main__.Node object at 0x00000000033A19E8>
<__main__.Node object at 0x00000000033A1A58>
ask
bit
```

when I should be getting:

```
dog
cat
ask
bit
```

I appreciate any help I can get to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Edit: I am only trying to change the remove_from_list method of my LinkedList class. The other parts do not need changing.

Edit: Changed my list so that i returned the data inside current. Now when I try test the following code:

```
my_list = LinkedList()

my_list.add(400)
print(my_list.remove_from_tail())
my_list.add(300)
print(my_list.remove_from_tail())
my_list.add(200)
print(my_list.remove_from_tail())
my_list.add(100)


print('List')
my_list.print_all()
```

I get the output:

```
400
400
300
List
100
200
```

When I should get

```
400
300
200
List
100
```

Edit: The problem I have right now is that I need to see if there is only one element in the list I need to make it so that current.head = None. How do I check if there is only one element in the list.

Answer (score 2):

`remove_from_tail()` returns a list item rather than data; so, your print should be as follows

```
print(my_list.remove_from_tail().get_data())
```

Comment: My mistake. This does print dog cat ask bit. However I'm trying to only change the LinkedList class so that it can remove the last element in the list.